# PutRequest not Supported [while spring hidden method is disabled]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-thymeleaf

I'm working on my first web app build with Java, Spring,and Thymeleaf. When I make a PutRequest for a login form, I get the following error message:

```
.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'PUT' is not supported]
```

Why do I get the message that PUT is not supported?

I already added `spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true` to the `application.properties`

**The login webpage**

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorate="~{layouts/layoutDefault}">
<body>
<div layout:fragment="content">
    <div class="container py-5 text-center">
        <form th:action="login" th:method="put" th:object="${loginForm}">
            <div class="purple_text mb-4">
                <h2>login</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <input th:field="*{email}" name="email" autocomplete="off" autofocus="" class="form-control mx-auto w-auto" placeholder="E-mail" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <input th:field="*{password}" name="password" autocomplete="off" class="form-control mx-auto w-auto" placeholder="Password" type="password">
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary submit_button" type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**The Controller**

```
@PutMapping( "/login-user")
    public String userLogin(@ModelAttribute("loginForm") Model model) {
        String email = (String) model.getAttribute("email");
        String password = (String) model.getAttribute("password");

       new StringFormattedMessage("email: %s\npassword: %s", email, password);


        boolean isValidLogin = appUserService.loginUser(email, password);


        if (isValidLogin){
            return "index";
        }

        else {
            return "register";
        }

    }
```

**The Service**

```
    public Boolean loginUser(String email, String password){
        Optional<AppUser> optionalAppUser = appUserRepository.findByEmailEqualsIgnoreCase(email);
        if (optionalAppUser.isPresent()) {
            AppUser appUserToLogin = optionalAppUser.get();
            String hashOfPassword = createHash(password);

            if(hashOfPassword.equals(appUserToLogin.getPassword())) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Email doesn't exists!");
        }
```

I hope someone can help me and point me in the right direction to fix the rookie-mistake(s).

Regards Martijn

Comment: Try action login-user

Comment: The PUT method is not supported in html. Instead use POST method with hidden method parameter.

Comment: Any special reason you are using PUT? It's not wrong, but it's more common to use POST for a login.

Answer (score 1):

In html you have `th:action="login"` but in your controller you have `@PutMapping( "/login-user")`. They should match to `th:action="@{/login}"` and `@PutMapping( "/login")` or `th:action="@{/login-user}"` and `@PutMapping( "/login-user")`

Note the missing `@ & {}` in your html form actions